# Lazy Patterns in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Could someone explain to me what this code snippet does (mainly last two lines)? Shouldn't I be able to pass Nothing to defValue? I tried and got an error "No instance for (Def, a0) arising from a use of 'defValue'"

```
class Def a where 
  defValue :: a -> a

instance Def a => Def (Maybe a) where
  defValue ~(Just x) = Just (defValue x)
```

Comment: You might need another pattern, e.g. defValue ~(Nothing) = Nothing. I doubt the Nothing pattern matches with Just x.

Comment: Where's the code where you're using this? The compiler shouldn't be able to infer `Def (Maybe a)` if it doesn't know anything about `a`, which is probably why you got that error. Also, are you sure that an irrefutable pattern is really what you should be doing here? Passing `Nothing` would lead to an exception even if it passed the typecheck.

Comment: @rickythesk8r I tried defValue ~(Nothing) = Nothing and that didn't work. I run defValue Nothing. Maybe I am passing Nothing in a wrong way?

Comment: Note that what you're probably trying to achieve doesn't need any argument at all: just use the signature `defValue :: a`. You don't need any of this awkward lazy pattern business if you never intend to use the argument. — [A `Default` class already exists](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-0.5.3/docs/Data-Default.html#t:Default) (albeit with a different `Maybe` instance, that always yields `Nothing`).

Comment: @Cubic there is no rest of the code. Just trying to figure out the code I have presented above. Could you tell me what what (Maybe a) means?

Comment: @Cubic it's called learning. If you don't have anything constructive to say, please don't comment.

Comment: @PaulKar. This wasn't meant as a jab at your knowledge, rather I'd like to know how you're learning Haskell. `Maybe` is one of the first datatypes that should get introduced, and type classes are imho something you should only think about once you're good with monomorphic haskell. Have you tried http://learnyouahaskell.com/ ?

Comment: @PaulKar. I think what he meant was that there is a certain order to learn things in that is the most effective, just as you wouldn't try to learn algebra before addition. Learning about `Maybe` should come before type classes.

Comment: @Cubic I know about monomorphic and polymorphic functions (just needed to google the name). I am learning Haskell by going over this Cheat Sheet (http://cheatsheet.codeslower.com/)

Comment: @rickythesk8r: no, that would completely defealt the point of a lazy pattern match!

Comment: @PaulKar. The Cheat Sheet is probably not a particularly effective way to learn Haskell.  However, even if you want to pursue that track, I'd suggest that their idea of introducing lazy pattern matching by using this typeclass is just nutty, for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with patterns, in fact you would have got the same error message if you'd declared

```
instance Def a => Def (Maybe a) where
  defValue = undefined
```

In fact, your code *should* work (as far as it possibly can, however I'd say your entire idea isn't good, very unsafe without need), but to use that `Maybe` instance you need an instance of the packed type to work with. For instance, if you add

```
instance Def Int where
  defValue _ = 0
```

then you can do

> DefVals> defValue (Just 1 :: Maybe Int)
>   Just 0
>   DefVals> defValue (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
>   Just 0

Comment: Why not do it like `def` does (and `Bounded` for that matter).  `class Def a where defValue :: a`  where an instance would be `defValue = Just defValue`?